# Preventing Postgres text search from assigning value to 'or' and 'not' terms

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I tracked down an issue in my project to our Postgres full text search feature, which was failing to locate matches on equal terms. Here is an example:

```
select ts_rank_cd(
               to_tsvector('Star Wars - Revenge of the Sith'),
               websearch_to_tsquery('Star Wars - Revenge of the Sith'),
               2
);
```

Returns 0 because as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html):

```
OR: the word “or” will be converted to the | operator.

-: a dash will be converted to the ! operator.
```

the char `-` causes `websearch_to_tsquery` to negate the word Revenge.

My question is if there is a clean way to prevent this function from performing this conversion, which in my case will always be unnecessary, or am I left with only the option of parsing the strings in advance to remove these terms?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You still have [`plainto_tsquery()` and `phraseto_tsquery()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#id-1.5.8.19.7.2.2.5.1.1.1) which don't do that. If you don't want the added functionality offered by `websearch_to_tsquery()`, use those instead.